# How to migrate gitlab from old version to new version?

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to restore from a backup file using this command `sudo gitlab-backup restore BACKUP=XXXXX`

its gives this error

```
GitLab version mismatch:
  Your current GitLab version (12.7.5) differs from the GitLab version in the backup!
  Please switch to the following version and try again:
  version: 11.9.8
```

How can restore from a backup file old version to new version?

Comment: Backup & restore documentation can be found here :- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For restore from a backup, a new server version needs same as the old server version.